# Use of ReflectionTestUtils.setField() in Junit testing to set a List of objects

Tags: java, junit, reflection

in my implementation , i have

`List<recordEntity> entityList = service.mapper(parameter1,parameter2);`

i need to set the value for this `entityList` with a static value for my unit testing,
i know that using `ReflectionsTestUtils` we can set value, even i have used this for another scenaro,

`ReflectionTestUtils.setField(classObject, "implementations", Collections.singletonMap("mapper", new DTOMapper()));`

but am not sure how to set a `list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a little example. I wrote a class with a List and using reflection set to this list a value:

```
public class ABC {

    public static List entityList = new ArrayList();

    public void method() {
        System.out.println(entityList);
    }
}
```

and junit test

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ABCTest {

    @InjectMocks
    ABC abc;

    @Test
    void myTest() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        List<ABC> staticEntityList = List.of(new ABC(), new ABC());

// Using reflection to set the value of entityList
        Field entityListField = ABC.class.getDeclaredField("entityList");
        entityListField.setAccessible(true);
        entityListField.set(abc, staticEntityList);
        abc.method();

    }
}
```

So size of it become to [image]